# How do I do a string operation on a named subquery?

Tags: mysql

The following query returns a non-specific error.

```
SELECT 
    mt.id
    ,mt.name
    ,(SELECT 
        fname
      FROM 
        othertable 
      WHERE 
        name = mt.name 
     ) AS first_name
     ,LOWER(first_name)
FROM 
mytable mt
```

How do I do string operation on this named column?

Comment: You can't use an alias in the SELECT clause

Comment: Well, it works in my context, but I've removed it. Question stands.

Comment: I mean `(...) AS first_name
     ,LOWER(first_name)` does not work since you reuse `first_name`  in the SELECT

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the result of a subselect in another column. If you want to have it lowercase, do that in the subselect. If you need both (lowercase and normal), do that either in two different subselects (it hurts to say that - would not advise it) or do that in the code.

Or maybe try to rewrite your code as a join.

```
SELECT 
    mt.id
    ,mt.name
    ,ot.fname
    ,LOWER(ot.fname) as lower_fname
FROM mytable mt  
JOIN othertable ot ON ot.name = mt.name
```

Comment: Yes on the JOIN. My bad.